# How do I change the default value of a field on a bound form that gets rendered in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In a Django project we have forms that have already been submitted where for some reason the person before me set the default value of a field to be one blank space (' ') and this is affecting some other functionality where we need to copy data (not relevant to go into detail for this question I don't think)

Anyway, here is a snippet from **models.py** where I changed the default value to '':

```
#inside class Meta   
base64_encoded_activation_key = models.CharField (max_length = 1000, default = '', blank = True, verbose_name = 'Activation Key')
```

Inside **views.py**

```
def edit_activation(request, id=None):
    ......

    activation = get_object_or_404(ActivationRecord, pk=id)
    .......
    .......
    .......
    else: # GET request
        form = ActivationRecordForm(instance=activation)
```

Now, this works fine if I create and submit a new form, but when I go back to an already submitted form then the value is still ' ' (which I guess is expected as the form has been submitted) but I don't know how to fix this to the new default value.

Comment: what do you mean by go back to old form? use browser back button?

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło as in viewing an already submitted form..

Comment: so the problem is when you open edit_activation with id you properly get the activation object and pass it to ActivationRecordForm as instance you get '' instead of ' '?

Comment: yes, except I want '' instead of ' ' @WaldemarPodsiadło

Comment: if someone saved it with ' ' it will be ' ' it is save that way in database. If you don't wan't that someone else save it with ' ' add field clean function that throws error if value is ' '

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło so once a default is saved it can't be altered? Now future forms and past forms will have a different default value...

Comment: you can run update script like ActivationRecord.objects.filter(base64_encoded_activation_key=' ').update(base64_encoded_activation_key='') it will change all objects in database that was saved with ' '.

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło Is it best practice to add this to my views.py file or does it need to be done when deploying the changes i've made above (i.e. changing the default value of the field)